# Regular expression for deleting everything between two HTML tags

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++, edit

I am trying to use Notepad++ to bulk-delete blocks of comments placed between `<HTML>` and `<HEAD>` tags in a large number of files.

Which regular expression phrase should I use?

Comment: Step 1: Choose your favourite programming language Step 2: use an html parser Step 3: ... Step 4: profit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one will work even if there are multiple `<HTML>`/`<HEAD>` tag pairs in the document:

```
(?i)<\!--(?:(?!<HTML[^>]*>).)*?-->(?=(?:(?!<HTML[^>]*>).)*?<HEAD[^>]*>)
```

Then ReplaceAll with empty string.

Settings:

[image]

Comment: Why should one bother to create a program when he can use one that allows him to do so?

Comment: Then, the question does not belong to SO.

Comment: It doesn't exactly do what requested, as it will not just remove comments. I tried to solve the issue, but I couldn't figure out a solution with notepad++.

Comment: It worked with the comments.  But in some files instead of just <html> it says <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">.  I tried substituting that in your string, but Notepad++ says not found.